# Why does Hyperledger Fabric not support Node version 7?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

In all Hyperledger fabric examples and samples, we see Node version 7+ is not supported. I couldn't find this question on Stack overflow

I know that it may be related to some package dependencies, but can anyone point to the specifics.

Comment: have you tried to clone the repo & compile the project with Node v7 and look at the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't published when the work began on the node SDK, and we didn't have the time/resource to address the issues with its use. I don't have the specifics, but we would welcome a [contribution](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/CONTRIBUTING.html) that enables node v7's use in addition to node 6.9+.